# invalid syntax using pandas read_excel method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read an Excel file with Pandas and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
path = 'FILENAME.xls'
sheet = 'SHEETNAME'
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet)
```

The code above throws me the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fsspec/mapping.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .core import url_to_fs
    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 314
        out[0] = (f"{out[0][1]}://", out[0][1], out[0][2])
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

python -V

```
Python 3.5.2
```

pd.**version**

```
'0.24.2'
```

Comment: What is your actual FILENAME ?

Comment: @BcK "data_rlc.xls"

Comment: You need to be using python 3.6 or above.

Comment: @quamrana i have been thinking about it [after reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231957/importing-gcsfs-in-datalab-is-giving-an-error), but without certainty

Comment: You should be using python 3.6 or above.

Comment: We had both mentioned the same stackoverflow, i need more information, @quamrana can you explain a bit writing an answer?

Comment: Here is documention.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings  Formatted strings literals with f-string... "New in Version 3.6".  Your error above is using f-string, f"{blah}".    You need to upgrade your python version.